# Can we find a positive integer sequence $\{n_k\}$ such that $\limsup_{k\to \infty}\frac{k}{k+n_k}$ is dense in some sense?

Tags: calculus

Can we find  a dense set $D\subset (0,1)$ (for example $D=\{\frac{j}{2^n}:0\le j\le 2^n-1, n\ge 1\}$) such that for any $x\in D$, there exists a **positive integer** sequence $\{n_k\}$ (which maybe dependents on $x$)satisfying $$\limsup\limits_{k\to \infty}\frac{k}{k+n_k}=x ?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $0<x<1$ let $$n_k= \left\lceil k(x^{-1}-1)\right\rceil $$
Then $$\lim_k{n_k\over k}=x^{-1}-1$$ and $$\lim_k{k\over k+n_k}=x$$

Comment: Many thanks!  @Ryszard Szwarc